# How to style default NavigationUI

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation

I'm using a `Frame` in a `Window` to display content and I added navigation with

```
<Frame NavigationUIVisibility="Visible" Name="FrameContent" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,34,-0.8,0.4" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
```

And in `Window.xsml.cs`

```
FrameContent.Navigate(new HomeView());
```

And the navigation bar looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way of changing the default look of this bar? Or is the only option to create a new one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my WPF app I created my own, The simplest version of it was like:

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="50" Background="DarkGray">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
         <Button Content="Back" Click="Back_Btn"/>
         <Button Content="Next" Click="Next_Btn"/>
     </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

In code behind:

```
private void Next_Btn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if (this.NavigationService.CanGoForward)
       NavigationService.GoForward();
    else
        NavigationService.Navigate(new HomeView());
}

private void Back_Btn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.NavigationService.CanGoBack)
        NavigationService.GoBack();
    else
        NavigationService.Navigate(new HomeView());
}
```

If you want you can design the buttons with [materialdesign](http://materialdesigninxaml.net/) package from NuGet for example.

The MVVM version of it is more complex.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to change the default look of the bar.

1. Have the xaml file with the frame open.
2. Open the document outline window.
   (From the Visual Studio Toolbar: View => Other Windows => Document Outline)
3. In the Document Outline window right click on the frame to display a context menu.
4. Select from the context menu: Edit Template => Edit a Copy...
5. Press OK on the Create Style Resource window.
6. Change the contents of Window.Resources to your liking.